# Can a user input a free-form value into a ComboBox that is not yet in the Items collection?

Tags: .net, winforms, combobox

This is probably a dumb question, but is there a way to setup a ComboBox so that a user can also add anything he wants into the ComboBox, without adding that item into Items collection? Basically, much like a simple TextBox functionality, but for a ComboBox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create an editable combobox by setting its `DropDownStyle` property to `ComboBoxStyle.Simple` or `ComboBoxStyle.DropDown`. See [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.comboboxstyle.aspx) for details.

[This page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa511458.aspx) also has a description and comparison of all drop down list options.

Comment: +1 Most likely, the asker is looking for `ComboBoxStyle.DropDown`.

Comment: Yes, that's it, thanks! I couldn't see this property as part of DataGridView column, but standalone, I can see it.